# Cannot find artifact in on-premise Sonatype Nexus which I can find in http://search.maven.org/

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

I'm searching for the latest version of spring-core.
http://search.maven.org/ returns "4.2.2.RELEASE".
Our on-premise Sonatype Nexus returns "4.1.6.RELEASE".
We have version 2.11.2-0 which comes built in with "Central" repository proxy.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the index update correctly configured? Does the index update work? BTW: You should update to 2.11.4...What exactly is the problem..

Comment: See here for some tips on how to fix this:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464518-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Download-Failures